# A simple subquery in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table `ORDERS` with columns `NAME` and `AMOUNT`.

I need to get a `NAME` and total `AMOUNT` of each product.

I have such a solution

```
select PRODUCT_NAME, SUM(AMOUNT) from ORDERS GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```

But I dont use any subqueries for achieving that. But the lesson that Im going through is about subqueries. May be Im wrong about this solution?

Comment: I have such a solution select PRODUCT_NAME, SUM(AMOUNT) from ORDERS GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME; But I dont use any subqueries for achieving that. But the lesson that Im going through is about subqueries. May be Im wrong about this solution?

Comment: Don't post code or additional information as commenst. **[edit]** your question

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple aggregation query without a need of sub query like:

```
SELECT name, SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Here is the original task "Show the names of products ordered along with their total amount." May be I do understand somth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is perfectly fine:

```
selectname, sum(amount)
from Orders
group by name
```

But, if you **must** use subquery, use this:

```
select o2.name,
  (select sum(amount)
   from Orders o1
   where o1.name = o2.name) as total
from
(select distinct name
from Orders) o2
```